# Multi touch android

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouch

Hy guys,
I am trying to run this code. If the user touches with one finger the background will turn black. If the user puts down next (second) finger the background will turn red.
The first finger works and the screen turns black, but nothing happens with the second finger.

```
public class MulticlickActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout background;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multiclick);

    background = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.multiclick_background);

    findViewById(R.id.multiclick_background).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public static final String TAG = "200.MulticlickActivity";

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)||(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN)){

                Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: " + event.getAction()
                        + " Action index  :" + event.getActionIndex());

                int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

                if (pointerIndex==0)
                background.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                if (pointerIndex==1)
                    background.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }


            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

}

Thanks very much

Comment: This code is fairly minimal, but have you read [Handling Multi-Touch Gestures](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html)

Comment: Added code to it. I looked there, yes.

Comment: Does using an `else if (pointerIndex == 1)` fix anything?

Comment: I figured it out. You have to use, event.getActionMasked. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to answer you own question and mark it as accepted to let others on the site know that was the solution

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You have to use, event.getActionMasked